# ¿Cómo eliminar y bloquear páginas con robots.txt?

Tags: google-search-console, robots.txt

Recibo diariamente errores de enlazamientos de **Urls** que no existe en mi sitio web.

A pesar de haber creado las únicas **Urls** que solo se pueden enlazar con el archivo **sitemap** Google igual enlace paginas que no existen en mi directorio ni en el código `html` ni tampoco **Urls** comentadas o ocultas.

Las siguientes **Urls** que no existen pero son enlazadas:

- catalogo.php
- catalogo.php?num=2
- mantenimiento-web.php
- salud.php
- faqs.php

La mayor parte de los artículos en la **Web** mencionan que se puede eliminar, bloquear paginas con `robots.txt`

Los `robots.txt` es un tema nuevo para mi a pesar de haberlos escuchado y observado.

Me pueden explicar como bloquear paginas, y cómo eliminar paginas, y como enlazarlo a mi sitio web para que google comience a utilizar los cambios.

Comment: En Google ([Información sobre los archivos robots.txt](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=es)) y Wikipedia ([Estándar de exclusión de robots](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Est%C3%A1ndar_de_exclusi%C3%B3n_de_robots)) tienes bastante información y ejemplos. No es necesario hacer una pregunta

Comment: @Josues te sugiero leas por favor [ask]  y no has realizado el [tour] para saber como funciona el sitio, definitivamente no es un foro.

Answer (score 1):

El uso del archivo `robots.txt` **no se refiere a la posibilidad de borrar *nada***. Es decir, **excluir no es sinónimo de *borrar***.

El archivo `robots.txt` solo sugiere **a los motores de búsqueda** qué páginas deberías omitir, pero no es obligatorio.

Tampoco impide a otra página que enlace a cualquier página del dominio.

#### Conclusión

`robots.txt` no sirve para lo que piensas que sirve.

#### Alternativa

Si siempre son esas páginas las enlazadas, crea un redirección 301 a una página con anuncios o a la portada. Así por lo menos ganas algunas visitas y, si todavía existe, PageRank de Google.

Comment: Mmm... Creo que sería innecesario crear una redirección con 301, porque al visitar aquella **Urls** no existente es direccionado a la página de error 404 que incluye el mapa de enlace del sitio. Debe haber una forma de evitar que google siga enlazando esos sitios...

Comment: Son errores menores, así que solo tienes que marcarlos como solucionados en la sección de errores de rastreo de la consola del webmaster.